# How to get a listbox to return it's results inside a range into the next empty row. Each selection another cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have a multiselect listbox and want to insert the selected items in a range from F to M into the last empty cells. I have already limited the possible selection to 8.

I already tried following code:

```
Dim i As Integer
With machwas.ListBox1
For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1
If .Selected(i) Then
If Cells(last, 6).Value = "" Then
ActiveSheet.Cells(last, 6).Value = .List(i)
If Cells(last, 7).Value = "" Then
ActiveSheet.Cells(last, 7).Value = .List(i)
If Cells(last, 8).Value = "" Then
ActiveSheet.Cells(last, 8).Value = .List(i)
If Cells(last, 8).Value = "" Then
ActiveSheet.Cells(last, 8).Value = .List(i)
If Cells(last, 9).Value = "" Then
ActiveSheet.Cells(last, 9).Value = .List(i)
If Cells(last, 10).Value = "" Then
ActiveSheet.Cells(last, 10).Value = .List(i)
If Cells(last, 11).Value = "" Then
ActiveSheet.Cells(last, 11).Value = .List(i)
If Cells(last, 12).Value = "" Then
ActiveSheet.Cells(last, 12).Value = .List(i)
If Cells(last, 13).Value = "" Then
ActiveSheet.Cells(last, 13).Value = .List(i)
If Cells(last, 14).Value = "" Then
ActiveSheet.Cells(last, 14).Value = .List(i)
End If
Else  
End If
Next i
```

But it shows me the first selection from the list in every last column.

Comment: You have the code for `8` repeating twice. Also, this can be reduced to 2 nested loops - when you see repeating code, think loops. Create a new variable for your row and increment that from 6 to 14

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it would help to see a simplified version of your code (easier the code is to read, the easier it usually is to de-bug)

---

You can reduce all of your code to the below nested loop:

```
Dim i As Long, x As Long

With machwas.ListBox1

    For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1
        If .Selected(i) Then
            For x = 6 To 14
                If Cells(last, x).Value = "" Then
                    ActiveSheet.Cells(last, x).Value = .List(i)
                End If
            Next x
        End If
    Next i

End With
```

I would consider qualifyig your instnaces of `Cells` as that could be the source of your issue.

Comment: thanks for the simplifying, but there is still the problem that it only iserting the first selected value from the list.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the simplifying, but there is still the problem that it only iserting the first selected value from the list.